# Passing data between table views using plist

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, plist

How do I pass data between two table views? I have `poet.plist` with 2 arrays: `name` and `biography`. When I run the app, second table view is empty. The first table view should list poets while the second table view lists works of poets.

First class

```
class Poets
{
    var poetName:String = ""
    var poetImage:String = ""
    var books=[Works]()
}
```

Second Class:

```
class Works {

    var nameWork = ""
    var workPoet = ""

    init(nameWork: String, workPoet: String) {
        self.nameWork = nameWork
        self.workPoet = workPoet
    }
}
```

First View Controller

```
let worksArray = booksDict[poet.poetName as String] as! NSArray
for work in worksArray {
    let dictionaryFromArray = work as! NSDictionary
    let workObject = Works(nameWork: dictionaryFromArray["nameWork"] as! String, workPoet: dictionaryFromArray["work"] as! String)
    poet.books.append(workObject)
}
```

How can I make a segue between the `UITableViewController` with names of poets and the `UITableViewController` with works of poets?

Comment: in `WorksTableViewController` the function `numberOfRowsInSection` should return `biography.count`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView` should return 1

Comment: @vadian Thank you.But I think I made a mistake with that code at all. I don't understand how to make by clicking on the row of the first table was the second table with the list. The data should be in plist. For example,the first table:the machines-the second table-the model of the machine. It's dictionary with arrays?How  can i do it?

Comment: Declaring the model variables outside a class is bad habit. Create a new file and declare a custom class `Poet` with properties `name`, `yearsOfLife`, `image` and `biography`. In `PoetsTableViewController` create a variable `poets = [Poet]()` . When reading the plist file, create `Poet` instances, populate the properties from `dict` and add the instances to `poets`. In `prepareForSegue` pass the `Poet` instance depending on the index path. In the `WorksTableViewController` populate the cells with the information in the `Poet` instance.

Comment: PS: now my comments are confusing because you removed all related information in your question

Comment: @vadian Thank you I'm a little edit the question. I tried to arrange everything as you write in the comments , but I do not understand , how passing data between table view controllers

Comment: There are many tutorials in the web, for example Ray Wenderlich is quite popular for his comprehensible tutorials. Look for a Master - Detail table view application.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/643383)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In 1st View Controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // ShowPoetWorks is your segue identifier which you can set in storyboard
    if segue.identifier == "ShowPoetWorks" {

        var secondVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController
        secondVC.poetName = poetName
    }
}
```

### In 2nd View Controller

- Define 2 field: `poetName` and `workCount`
- Override function `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return workCount  
  }
  ```
- In viewDidLoad, load poet works base on poetName and call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: you mean *How can I make a segue between the UITableViewController with names of poets and the UITableViewController with works of poets?*? 
Drag and drop from poets UITableViewController to works UITableViewController.